# Cakephp 2.x call delete method from user controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have `USER` model which consist subtypes of many different users(doctor,nursing home etc), now based upon that subtype I want to delete his user data as well as his sub type data. I made delete method on each type of user's controller which can delete all relational data of that user.
Now is there any way based on user's type so that I call the `delete method` of that user (let for doctor it's delete method define on `DoctorsController`) from User Controller and delete all data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways.

Let's assume you have two variables, one is `$type` where you store your *subtype name* and one is `$type_id` where you store the *ID of the subtype* you want to delete.

**1)** If your `User` model has a relationship with your subtype model (Doctor, Nursing home...), maybe `hasMany` or `belongsTo`, then you can access your related model directly.

```
$this->User->{$type}->delete($type_id);
```

**2)** If you don't have a relationship between `User` and your subtype model, then you can use ClassRegistry.

```
ClassRegistry::init($type)->delete($type_id);
```

Note that if `$type` is *'Doctor'*, for example, you are not calling methods in `DoctorsController`, but methods in `Doctor` Model.

Comment: Thanks that will do, but if there is any method so that I can call delete method from controller by the same way that will be much useful.

Comment: @ashishTripathi Yes, you can use RequestAction (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3arequestAction) or import your controller and instantiate it, but I would not recommend neither of them. Always try to keep your logic in Models.

Comment: @Deimoks , sir u hav indepth knowledge of cakePHP . +1 for helping people :)